# How to pass Object in as string list in c# controller?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs

```
public class abcController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "A","B","C"};
    }

}
```

I want to pass object containing name, id and image in string array..
How to accomplish this??
Please help me..
Also tell me how to access any specific element in this object..

Comment: I am using C# and .net. and angularjs in front end

Comment: I recommend you look at Model Binding.

Comment: Please help with solution ..I am new to this

Comment: What are you new to, C#, ASP.Net, Angular or programming in general?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for. I have put this in Console app. You can just copy the logic to your controller

```
        public class ImageInformation
        {
            public ImageInformation(string name, string id, string image)
            {
                Name = name;
                Id = id;
                Image = image;
            }
            public string Name { get; private set; }
            public string Id { get; private set; }
            public string Image { get; private set; }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ImageInformation> Get()
        {
            return new List<ImageInformation> { 
               new ImageInformation("A", "1", "A.jpg"),
               new ImageInformation("B", "2", "B.jpg"),
               new ImageInformation("C", "3", "C.jpg"),
            };
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var images = Get();
            var imageA = images.First(x => x.Name == "A");
            var imageAName = imageA.Name;
            var imageAId = imageA.Id;
            var imageAImage = imageA.Image;

            Console.WriteLine(imageAName);
            Console.WriteLine(imageAId);
            Console.WriteLine(imageAImage);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use XML Serializing.

What XML Serializing does is it converts an object to XML format (which is a string) and then when you want to get the object back you can use XML Deserializer to Deserialize the XML string format to the original object.

for example, your object can be a class that contains a string name, int ID, string imagePath, let's call that class person.

## The Class

```
[System.Serializable]
public class person
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string imagePath { get; set; }
}
```

## Class Notes

- Make sure that the class has the system.Serializable attribute.
- Make sure that all the fields and properties you have are public (otherwise the program will crash !).

## The XML Manager

- Make sure that you have the namespace below otherwise you won't be able to use any of the methods listed

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

The XML_Manager class Which we'll put our methods in :-

```
public static class XML_Manager
    {
        // The Serializing Method
        public static string serializeObject<T>(T toSerialize)
        {
            // Create the result string variable
            string result = "";

            // Create a new StringWriter that will carry the serialization and dispose it as soon as it's done it's job
            using(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                // Create the serializer that will serialize the object of type (T)
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                // Serialize the object and put the result on the StringWriter (sw)
                xs.Serialize(sw, toSerialize);

                // Exctract the result from the StringWriter (sw) by converting it to string
                result = sw.ToString();
            }

            // Return the result
            return result;
        }

        // The Deserializing Method
        public static T deserializeObject<T>(string XmlString)
        {
            // Create the result variable of type (T)
            T Result;

            // Create a new StringReader that will carry the XmlString and dispose it as soon as it's done it's job
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(XmlString))
            {
                // Create the serializer that will deserialize the object of type (T)
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                // Deserialize the XmlString and extract the object
                Result = (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);
            }

            // Return the result
            return Result;
        }
    }
```

## Putting the scripts to work

```
            // Create a new person
            person p = new person();

            // Set the name
            p.name = "John";

            // Set the ID
            p.id = 2345;

            // Set the Image Path
            p.imagePath = "desktop";

            // the xml serialized string
            string xmlString = XML_Manager.serializeObject(p);

            // the deserialized person
            person deserializePerson = XML_Manager.deserializeObject<person>(xmlString);

            // Show the serialized string
            MessageBox.Show(xmlString);

            // Show the deserialized object
            MessageBox.Show($"Name: {deserializePerson.name}, Id: {deserializePerson.id}, Image Path: {deserializePerson.imagePath}");
```